# vim repeat find next character 'x'

Tags: vim, repeat

I often navigate in vim by `f x` to find next occurrence of character 'x',
but overlook that there is a word (or more words) containing 'x' in between the word I want to edit and the beginning cursor position.

So i have to `f x` again, which is kind of annoying since there is this nice button `.`, which does repeat the last command. So is there a way to repeat `f x` with a single button press.

Answer (score 301, accepted):

The command to repeat an <kbd>f</kbd> is <kbd>;</kbd> (semicolon); <kbd>,</kbd> (comma) reverses the direction of the search.

Comment: Is there a useful reason you can't use `.` for this? That was the command I expected to work.

Comment: @DanielKaplan It makes sense to map the novement, i.e. the search for a character (`f` and `;`), to a different character than the repetition of an edit (`.`). This allows you to do fast searches and changes to the search results. If you want to replace some `+` in a line with `*` you could do something like this (skipping some characters and replacing others): `f+r*;.;;.;.;;;.`

Comment: Is there a way to remap those commands? A lot of people use `,` for leader.

Comment: @rk1 Change the leader with :let mapleader=" " (if you want a space)

Comment: @DrEval Sure, but I want to keep my leader as `,` and still have reverse search. Anyway, now I'm a happy user of vim-easymotion.

Answer (score 25):

Time has passed since I asked this question - nowadays I use [vim-easymotion](https://github.com/easymotion/vim-easymotion), which makes the need for `;` almost unnecessary.

This plugin allows to jump to a certain letter directly - triggering the plugin makes all letters grey except for all 'x' on the screen - and those are replaced by red letters which you can press to jump directly to it.

[image: easymotion in use]

Answer (score 5):

To add  to @Jeremiah Willcock answer, We can add count to `f` command to go to the nth occurrence `[count]f{char}`. For e.g.

`2fx` => goes to the second occurrence of `x` [if available]

similarly we can use the same counter to `;` and `,`. For e.g.

`2;` => goes to the second occurrence of last search [if available]
`2,` => goes to the second occurrence of last search in reverse [if available]

This is very useful when using it with `c{motion}`(change) or `d{motion}`(delete). For e.g. 
If we want to change or delete to 3rd occurrence of a char we can do

`c3fx` => change to 3rd occurrence of character `x` (included)
`d3fx` => delete to 3rd occurrence of character `x` (included)